# What's an example of a non-strong monad on the category of sets?

Tags: category-theory, monads

If I understand the definition correctly, it seems to me that all the monads I know of on the category of sets can be viewed as [strong monads](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/strong+monad) in a natural way.

For example, if $T$ is the free group monad then there's an obvious map $$S : X \times T(\{a,b\}) \rightarrow T(X \times \{a,b\})$$ which I guess is the left strength.

For example, $$S(x,\,a^2b^{-3}a) = (x,a)^2(x,b)^{-3}(x,a).$$

Indeed, this same definitional pattern can be simulated for any monad on $\mathbf{Set}$ that I can think of.

> **Question.** What's an example of a monad on the category of sets that is not a strong monad in a natural way?

Comment: I don't think there are such examples, because a tensorial strength on an endofunctor $F$ on a closed monoidal category can be thought of as a way to enrich $F$ into a $V$-functor; but when $V=\mathbf{Sets}$ your $F$ is already enriched ! See [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/tensorial+strength#description) for some explanations.

Comment: Alternatively, the same explanation is also [there](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2009/07/the_monads_hurt_my_head_but_no.html#c025390), where there may be a bit more helpful context.